# ColdFusion: Waiting for files to be created before acting on them

Tags: coldfusion, dos

I have a series of files being generated with the following code:

```
<cfloop list="#clients#" index="idx">
    <cfexecute name="c:\windows\system32\cmd.exe" arguments='/c #APPLICATION.basepath#scripts\foldersize\dirP.bat #idx#'/>
    <cfexecute name="c:\windows\system32\cmd.exe" arguments='/c #APPLICATION.basepath#scripts\foldersize\dirA.bat #idx#'/>
</cfloop>
```

This fires off a number of requests to list those directories and pipe the `findstr` filter through to the respective files simultaneously...

What I need though is a way to ensure that the files are completely created before I use `CFFILE` on them to read in the output...

I'd use `FileExists()`, but it acts a little prematurely and I need it to be dead certain that the file is complete... Any ideas how to resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`<cfexecute>` has the `timeout` parameter](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/10.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7d56.html). Just set it to a high number.

It might be necessary to increase the overall request timeout.

```
<cfsetting requesttimeout="300">
```

Comment: What if the file write exceeds the timeout? You will then throw an error because the timeout exceeded.  Also, using cfsetting will set the timeout for the entire request not just the cfexecute.  Increasing timeout has no barring on file write completeness. You state you need to be "dead certain" that the file is done writing.  If so, this is not the correct solution.

Comment: @DaveFerguson And what if an out-of-memory error occurs or the disk fails? Then your suggestion does not guarantee success either. Apart from that I see a that your code bails out of the endless loop after 60 iterations. This means that the amount of guarantees your solution can give towards write completeness is *exactly equal* to the amount of guarantees my solution can give, only is yours several orders of magnitude more complicated.

Comment: Also worth mentioning that without a timeout value cfexecute will return immediately. Any time the code following it depends on the execution of the task, the timeout should be _at least_ 2.

Comment: @Tomalak While I agree that the code i gave does have a catch in it to prevent an infinite loop.  That is just smart coding.  That can be adjusted to be longer if necessary.  The code I gave is more complicated.  It is complicated because it actually checks the file.  While your solution just allows the request to run longer.

Comment: While @DaveFerguson's code may be 'several orders of magnitude' more complex, it would be easier to modify to make 'dead certain' the file is done being written than the solution that just sets the timeout parameter higher. The code is complex because it is a complex problem to solve. I am all for simple solutions, but this is a situation where simple will only mask a problem rather than solve it.

Comment: @Scott I'm aware of the fact that I exaggerated. ;) My point is that there is no way of knowing whether an external process is *really* done other than waiting for it to finish and inspect its return code. A whole lot of real-world scenarios can be migrated by waiting long enough (you could use `timeout="0"` to have it wait forever) and Adam's code really does nothing other than busy waiting. That's all-right, and if you can make assumptions about the file it might be ever better than `timeout` - but if you can't, it's just as good (or bad) as `timeout`, only a lot less convenient.

Comment: @DaveFerguson's answer is the better answer here, for the reasons Dave and Scott cite. This answer just delays the original scenario, but in no way solves it.

Comment: @Adam Why? Dave's answer waits until the file is stable for two seconds (which means absolutely nothing, it's a baseless assumption as good as any other guess) and cops out after 60 seconds. It's exactly like waiting 60 seconds. It's even worse. In the best case the process needs 0 seconds to finish, the function waits 2 seconds anyway. At worst the process needs more than 2 seconds to append a new line to the file, in which case the function finishes with a false positive. I don't see how that is better. Enlighten me.

Comment: Because it actually makes an attempt to check the condition that is the requirement in the original question. Yours doesn't: it just relies on luck to work. Dave's approach needs polish, but the general technique is sound.

Comment: @Adam *"Makes an attempt?"* Seriously? *"Needs polish?"* - It relies on luck exactly the same amount as my solution. The assumption that a when a file does not change for some arbitrary amount of time then the process must be done is completely unfounded. Not only that, it's outright stupid. It's the same logical fallacy that makes you assume that a virus scanner makes your system more secure. *"It's something, therefore it must be better than nothing!"* Sorry, I'm not buying this.

Answer (score 4):

Setting a high timeout doesn't actually validate file write completion.  It just allows for code to run longer.  Also, just being able to read the file doesn't mean it is written either.  What you need to do is watch the file size for changes.  But you have to be careful not to cause a blocking condition when getting the file info.  An attempt to read the file without creating a non-blocking read could disrupt the file write and cause it to fail.  This can be accomplished using the following code.

Given a file, the code will run till the file is written and not locked.  This code is a few years old but you should get the idea.

```
<cffunction name="isFileWritten" access="public" returntype="string">
<cfargument name="source" type="struct" required="yes"/>

<cfscript>
    thisFile = source;
    fileRead = createObject("java", "java.io.FileInputStream");
    thisThread = CreateObject("java", "java.lang.Thread");
    loopCT = 1;
    while(1 EQ 1)
    {
        try
        {
            fileRead.init(thisFile);
            break;
        }
        catch(any ecpt)
        {
            thisThread.sleep(1000);
        }
        incrementValue(loopCT);
        if(loopCT GT 60)
        {
            fileRead.close();
            return;
        }
    }

    loopCT = 1;
    while(1 EQ 1)
    {
        sizeA = fileRead.available();
        thisThread.sleep(1000);
        sizeB = fileRead.available();
        if(sizeA EQ sizeB)
        {
            thisThread.sleep(1000);
            sizeC = fileRead.available();
            if(sizeC EQ sizeB)
            {
                break;
            }
        }
        incrementValue(loopCT);

        if(loopCT GT 60)
        {
            fileRead.close();
            return;
        }
    }
    fileRead.close();
</cfscript>

<cfreturn>
```

Comment: OOh Dave... VAR yer variables mate! Also why `1 EQ 1` rather than just `true` on your loop condition? And doesn't `sleep()` achieve the same thing your `java.lang.Thread` stuff effects?

Comment: @adam If you look before the code you will see that I said "This code is a few years old but you should get the idea." I admit is poorly written and I should probably update the code in the post with better code.

Comment: Sorry if this is a dumb question, but could anyone explain how to arrive at a struct for the source variable? So, say I want to run this function for a file c:\temp\myfile.pdf, how would I define the struct that I'm passing to this function?

Answer (score 2):

You really should show your batch code. Presumably your batch scripts produce files with a particular name or extension, and you then you later use FileExists() to look for the existence of a file with the appropriate name to process.

I suspect the simplest solution would be to modify your batch scripts such that it first creates a file with an alternate name that is not recognized. When the file is complete, have your batch script use MOVE to rename the file to the correct name. In this way your FileExists() test can be sure that the file is complete.

Comment: This is actually probably the best answer: simply don't make the file available at all until its ready.

Comment: I agree with Adam.  This sounds like a problem that is better solved outside CF.  Can it be solved with CF?  Sure, Dave proved that with his answer (OK, it uses Java, but CF is Java).  But solving it in the batch script may make more sense.  CF doesn't have to be used to solve every problem.